# Is the following code thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

The following code uses a double checked pattern to initialize variables. I believe the code is thread safe, as the map wont partially assigned even if two threads are getting into `getMap()` method at the same time. So I don't have to make the map as volatile as well. Is the reasoning correct? NOTE: The map is immutable once it is initialized.

```
class A {

    private Map<String, Integer> map;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public static Map<String, Integer> prepareMap() {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("test", 1);
        return map;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getMap() {
        if (map == null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (map == null) {
                    map = prepareMap();
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a separate lock object? Why a static method from an instance method?

Answer (score 4):

According to the top names in the Java world, no it is not thread safe.  You can read why here: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

You better off using ConcurrentHashmap or synchronizing your Map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Edit:  If you only want to make the initialization of the map thread safe (so that two or more maps are not accidentally created) then you can do two things.  1) initialize the map when it is declared.  2) make the getMap() method synchronized.

Comment: Note: my map is not modified once it is initialized, in that case is the above code threadsafe?

Comment: Still not thread safe.  If you want the initialization of the map to be thread safe then just include the initialization when it is declared as a object variable.

Comment: Can you explain why it is not threadsafe?

Comment: You have to read the article, it explains it a lot better than I can.  You can male the getMap() method synchronized.  Double checked locking is a way to bypass having to synchronize the method.  But, as the article explains, there still could be a way for two maps to be created.

Comment: @vinayag It is very difficult to explain in a reasonably short answer. Please, please if you are seriously considering using the code in the question read the referenced article.

Comment: A key paragraph that may be worth quoting in the answer as a reason for not trying to go into more detail: "There are lots of reasons it doesn't work. The first couple of reasons we'll describe are more obvious. After understanding those, you may be tempted to try to devise a way to "fix" the double-checked locking idiom. Your fixes will not work: there are more subtle reasons why your fix won't work. Understand those reasons, come up with a better fix, and it still won't work, because there are even more subtle reasons."

Comment: I have added an answer, intended as a supplement to this one, that explains one of the failing cases in my own words.

Answer (score 1):

No, your reasoning is wrong, access to the map is not thread safe, because the threads that call `getMap()` after the initialization may not invoke `synchronized(lock)` and thus are not in [happens-before relation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) to other threads.

The map has to be `volatile`.

Comment: Note once the map is initialized, it is never modified. So effectively final, and my question is to understand if the compiler reordering can cause any issues here by any means.

Comment: The map can be returned partially constructed from `getMap()` by a thread that didn't sychronize.

Comment: @vinayag It is not enough to think about compiler reordering. You also need to consider the possibility that two threads are running on different processors with different caches.

Comment: In getMap method, I am assigning the result from prepareMap() method. The assignment is happening in one instruction. So how a thread can see only a partially constructed map?

Comment: @vinayag I'm assuming you don't just want it to get the correct value of the pointer to the map object, you want each thread to see a fully and correctly initialized HashMap.

Comment: NOTE: There are no other methods to directly access the map. Just given the piece of the code, is it thread safe? All the threads are going to call getMap() method to access the map.

Comment: Yes. I want each thread to see fully constructed hash map. How a thread can see partially constructed map? I am assuming when I assign a variable to point to a map, there is no copying of the map is happening. So my understanding is that no threads can see partially constructed map.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be optimized by inlining to

```
  public Map<String,Integer> getMap()
  {
     if(map == null)
     {
        synchronized(lock)
        {
           if(map == null)
           {
               map = new HashMap<>();  // partial map exposed
               map.put("test", 1);               
           }
        }
     }
     return map;
  }
}
```

Having a HashMap under concurrent read and write is VERY dangerous, don't do it. 
Google *HashMap infinite loop*.

---

Solutions -

Expand `synchronized` to the entire method, so that reading `map` variable is also under lock. This is a little expensive.

Declare `map` as `volatile`, to prevent reordering optimization. This is simple, and pretty cheap.

Use an immutable map. The `final` fields will also prevent exposing partial object state. In your particular example, we can use `Collections.singletonMap`. But for maps with more entries, I'm not sure JDK has a public implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one example of how things can go wrong. To fully understand the issues, there is no substitute for reading [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html), referenced in a [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31664077/1798593).

To get anything approaching the full flavor, think about two processors, A and B, each with its own caches, and a main memory that they share.

Suppose Thread A, running on Processor A, first calls `getMap`. It does several assignments inside the synchronized block. Suppose the assignment to `map` gets written to main memory first, before Thread A reaches the end of the synchronized block.

Meanwhile, on Processor B, Thread B also calls `getMap`, and does not happen to have the memory location representing `map` in its cache. It goes out to main memory to get it, and its read happens to hit just after Thread A's assignment to `map`, so it sees a non-null `map`. Thread B does not enter the synchronized block.

At this point, Thread B can go ahead and attempt to use the HashMap, despite the fact that Thread A's work on creating it has not yet been written to main memory. Thread B may even have the memory pointed to by `map` in its cache because of a prior use.

If you are tempted to try to work around this, consider the following quote from the referenced article:

> There are lots of reasons it doesn't work. The first couple of reasons
>   we'll describe are more obvious. After understanding those, you may be
>   tempted to try to devise a way to "fix" the double-checked locking
>   idiom. Your fixes will not work: there are more subtle reasons why
>   your fix won't work. Understand those reasons, come up with a better
>   fix, and it still won't work, because there are even more subtle
>   reasons.

This answer only contains one of the most obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not thread safe.

The basic reason is that you can have reordering of operations you don't even see in the Java code. Let's imagine a similar pattern with an even simpler class:

```
class Simple {
    int value = 42;
}
```

In the analogous `getSimple()` method, you assign `/* non-volatile */ simple = new Simple ()`. What happens here?

1. the JVM allocates some space for the new object
2. the JVM sets some bit of this space to 42 (for `value`)
3. the JVM returns the address of this space, which is then assigned to `space`

Without synchronization instructions to prohibit it, these instructions can be reordered. In particular, steps 2 and 3 can be ordered such that `simple` gets the new object's address before the constructor finishes! If another thread then reads `simple.value`, it'll see a value 0 (the field's default value) instead of 42. This is called seeing a partially-constructed object. Yes, that's weird; yes, I've seen things like that happen. It's a real bug.

You can imagine how if the object is a non-trivial object, like HashMap, the problem is even worse; there are a lot more operations, and so more possibilities for weird ordering.

Marking the field as volatile is a way of telling the JVM, "any thread that reads a value from this field must also read all operations that happened before that value was written." That prohibits those weird reorderings, which guarantees you'll see the fully-constructed object.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you declare the `lock` as `volatile`, this code may be translated to non-thread-safe bytecode.

The compiler may optimize the expression `map == null`, cache the value of the expression and thus read the `map` property only once.

`volatile Map<> map` instructs the Java VM to always read the property `map` when it is accessed. Thsi would forbid such optimization from the complier.

Please refer to [JLS Chapter 17. Threads and Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)

Comment: The lock is final and eagerly initialized.  Why would making it volatile matter?  Convince me.

Comment: why volatile matters here? final is good enough. My question is also different though.

Comment: @Makoto explaind in the answer

Comment: You should do some more explaining.  I've not heard the compiler deciding to optimize something like that which isn't a compile-time guarantee before.

Comment: @Makoto Provided a link where you can read about the exact synchronization requirements for JVM implementations. Nothing forbids the Java compiler to do optimisation or even instruction reordering if it is matches those.